# grep or pmatch?

Tags: r, lookup

I am trying to import a series of files from directory and convert each of them into a dataframe. I would also like to use the file title to create two new columns with title-dependent values. Input files have the format: `xx_yy.out`
Where XX can currently be one of three values. YY currently has two possible values. In the future these numbers will go up.

---

Edit of Solution based on the comments (see below for the original question)

---

edited again to reflect suggestions of @JoshO'Brien

```
filelist <- as.list(dir(pattern = ".*.out"))

for(i in filelist) {

    tempdata  <- read.table(i)                  #read the table
    filelistshort <- gsub(".out$", "", i)       #remove the end of the file
    tempsplit <- strsplit(filelistshort, "_")   #remove the underscore
    xx <- sapply(tempsplit, "[", 1)             #get xx
    yy <- sapply(tempsplit, "[", 2)             #get yy
    tempdata$XX <- xx                           #add XX column
    tempdata$YY <- yy                           #add YY column
    assign(gsub(".out","",i), tempdata)         # give the dataframe a shortened name

}
```

Below is the original code showing that I wanted to use some means to ge teh XX and YY values but wasn't sure of the best way:

My outline (after @romanlustrik [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756989/how-to-load-data-quickly-into-r) ) is as follows:

```
filelist <- as.list(dir(pattern = ".*.out"))
lapply(filelist, FUN = function(x) {
    xx <- grep() or pmatch()
    yy <- grep() or pmatch()
    x <- data.frame(read.table(x)) 
    x$colx <- xx
    x$coly <- yy
    return(x)
})
```

where the `xx <-`  and `yy <-` lines would be a lookup based on either pmatch or grep. I am playing around to make either one work but would welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can assume that your file names will contain only a single `"_"`, I wouldn't use `grep()` or `pmatch()` at all.

`strsplit()` seems to provide a cleaner and simpler solution:

```
filelist <- c("aa_mm.out", "bb_mm.out", "cc_nn.out")

# Remove the trailing ".out"
rootNames <- gsub(".out$", "", filelist)

# Split string at the "_"
rootParts <- strsplit(rootNames, "_")

# Extract the first and second parts into character vectors
xx <- sapply(rootParts, "[", 1)
yy <- sapply(rootParts, "[", 2)

xx
# [1] "aa" "bb" "cc"
yy
# [1] "mm" "mm" "nn"
```

Comment: @zach -- No problem.  For compactness and reliability, you might want to put all of your calculations into a single `for()` loop or call to `lapply()`.  If you go the `lapply()` route, you'll need to ensure that assignment takes place into the global environment, by specifying  `assign("objectName", object, envir=.GlobalEnv)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly hack, but gets the job done.

```
fl <- c("12_34.out", "ab_23.out", "02_rk.out")
xx <- regexpr(pattern = ".._", text = fl)
XX <- (substr(fl, start = xx, stop = xx + attr(xx, "match.length")-1))
  [1] "12" "ab" "02"
yy <- regexpr(pattern = "_..", text = fl)
YY <- (substr(fl, start = yy + 1, stop = yy + attr(yy, "match.length")-1))
  [1] "34" "23" "rk"
```