# Speed up RData load

Tags: r, io

I've checked several related questions such is this

[How to load data quickly into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756989/how-to-load-data-quickly-into-r)

I'm quoting specific part of the most rated answer

> It depends on what you want to do and how you process the data further. In any case, loading from a binary R object is always going to be faster, provided you always need the same dataset. The **limiting speed here is the speed of your harddrive, not R**. The binary form is the internal representation of the dataframe in the workspace, so there is no transformation needed anymore

I really thought that. However, life is about experimenting. I have a 1.22 GB file containing an igraph object. That's said, i don't think what I found here is related to the object class, mainly because you can load('file.RData') even before you call "library".

Disks in this server are pretty cool. As you can check in the reading time to memory

```
user@machine data$ pv mygraph.RData > /dev/null
1.22GB 0:00:03 [ 384MB/s] [==================================>] 100% `
```

However when I load this data from R

```
>system.time(load('mygraph.RData'))
   user  system   elapsed 
178.533  16.490   202.662
```

So it seems loading *.RData files is 60 times slower than disk limits, which should mean R actually **does** something while "load".

I've got the same feeling using differentes R versions with different hardware, it's just this time I got patience to make benchmarking (mainly because with such a cool disk storage, it was terrible how long the load actually takes)

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

---

After ideas in answers

```
save(g,file="test.RData",compress=F)
```

Now the file is 3.1GB against 1.22GB before. In my case, loading uncompress is a bit faster (disk is not my bottleneck by far)

```
> system.time(load('test.RData'))
user  system elapsed 
126.254   2.701 128.974
```

Reading the uncompressed file to memory takes like 12 seconds, so I confirm most the time is spent in setting the enviroment

I'll be back with RDS results, sounds like interesting

---

Here we are, as prommised

```
system.time(saveRDS(g,file="test2.RData",compress=F))
user  system elapsed 
7.714   2.820  18.112
```

And I get a 3.1GB just like "save" uncompressed, although md5sum is different, probably because `save` also stores the object name

Now reading...

```
> system.time(a<-readRDS('test2.RData'))
user  system elapsed 
41.902   2.166  44.077
```

So combining both ideas (uncompress and RDS) runs 5 times faster. Thanks for your contributions!

Comment: Funny how I got a different experience. I have a 300 MB file which through `saveRDS` became 5 GB large. The compressed file was read by `load` in 383.81 seconds, while the second took `readRDS` 1085.14 secs. I've just found about `saveRDS`, so I'll take a closer look at the function, but my first experience wasn't what I expected.

Answer (score 12):

`save` compresses by default, so it takes extra time to uncompress the file.  Then it takes a bit longer to load the larger file into memory.  Your `pv` example is just copying the compressed data to memory, which isn't very useful to you. ;-)

UPDATE:

I tested my theory and it was incorrect (at least on my Windows XP machine with 3.3Ghz CPU and 7200RPM HDD).  Loading compressed files is faster (probably because it reduces disk I/O).

The extra time is spent in `RestoreToEnv` (in `saveload.c`) and/or `R_Unserialize` (in `serialize.c`).  So you could make loading faster by changing those files, or maybe by using `saveRDS` to individually save the objects in `myGraph.RData` then somehow using `loadRDS` across multiple R processes to load the data into shared memory...

Answer (score 5):

For variables that big, I suspect that most of the time is taken up inside the internal C code (http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/saveload.c).  You can run some profiling to see if I'm right. (All the R code in the `load` function does is check that your file is non-empty and hasn't been corrupted.

As well as reading the variables into memory, they (amongst other things) need to be stored inside an R environment.

The only obvious way of getting a big speedup in loading variables would be to rewrite the code in a parallel way to allow simultaneous loading of variables.  This presumably requires a substantial rewrite of R's internals, so don't hold your breath for such a feature.

Comment: what would be your advice to save a large object, say an environment temporarily?

Comment: @MattBannert It depends upon your use case, but start with `save`.

Comment: Tried to save single environment containing los of objects. And save was soooo slow, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why RData files take a while to load is that the de-compression step is single-threaded.

The fastSave R package allows using parallel tools for saving and restoring R sessions:

https://github.com/barkasn/fastSave

But it only works on UNIX (You should still be able to open the files on other platforms though).