# probe a huge RData file without fully loading it

Tags: r, bigdata

Suppose I have a RData file of 8 G, loading it in the memory will take quite long time. Instead of waiting, is there a way to probe how the stored data table or data frame looks like without fully loading the RData file?

Comment: Don't think you can. You'd better save chunks of your dataset in different files.

Comment: I dont think for Rdata file. You may want to have a look at `fst` package. Not only (very) fast serialization but you can access one column directly.

Comment: also, may be of interest: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559628/speed-up-rdata-load?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559628/speed-up-rdata-load?rq=1)