# How to load and view large R workspace

Tags: r

I'm working on a genetic research project. A previous researcher on the project saved all the data she was working with in a 6.33 GB R workspace (.RData file), but did not document the values needed later in the project anywhere besides this file.

I have tried loading the workspace in R, but it's been attempting to load for ~3 hours and nothing has come from that.

Is there any other way to view this workspace or break it up so it can be opened in different segments?

Comment: Please post the code you used to try to load the workspace.

Comment: Probably not. If the rdata file is very large and compressed, it may actually take hours to load, depending on your computer.

Comment: I can't speak to its effectiveness (and it has 0 upvotes, so neither can anyone else), but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52783943/8366499) suggests a package that supposedly allows parallelized loading. It might still be better to just let it run overnight, or borrow a faster computer to load the file and then re-save without compression or in smaller chunks