# Quicker way to read single column of CSV file

Tags: r, performance, optimization, csv, io

I am trying to read a single column of a `CSV` file to `R` as quickly as possible. I am hoping to cut down on standard methods in terms of the time it takes to get the column into RAM by a factor of 10.

What is my motivation? I have two files; one called `Main.csv` which is 300000 rows and 500 columns, and one called `Second.csv` which is 300000 rows and 5 columns. If I `system.time()` the command `read.csv("Second.csv")`, it will take 2.2 seconds. Now if I use either of the two methods below to read the first column of `Main.csv` (which is 20% the size of `Second.csv` since it is 1 column instead of 5), it will take over 40 seconds. **This is the same amount of time as it takes to read the whole 600 Megabyte file** -- clearly unacceptable.

- Method 1

  ```
  colClasses <- rep('NULL',500)

  colClasses[1] <- NA
  system.time(
  read.csv("Main.csv",colClasses=colClasses)
  ) # 40+ seconds, unacceptable
  ```
- Method 2

  ```
   read.table(pipe("cut -f1 Main.csv")) #40+ seconds, unacceptable
  ```

How to reduce this time? I am hoping for an `R` solution.

Comment: You can load your data into database and select only required column or use HDF5 files instead of csv.

Comment: @zero323 I need something that can be `io` with all of: `Python`, `Java`, `R`.

Comment: `require(data.table); fread( "path/to/file/Main.csv" )` will give you an instant speed improvement.

Comment: My rather [old POC package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/saves/index.html) might be interesting here that provides a way to write a `data.frame` in a special binary format that can be used later for reading only a few variables at a time. Basically it's a wrapper around `save/readRDS` and writing the columns to separate files etc. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756989/how-to-load-data-quickly-into-r

Comment: @SimonO101 from 40 seconds to 15 seconds. Well done.

Comment: @SimonO101 Can you give an example how to read a single column? I used the same `colClasses` as in my example but it will just read the whole 600Mb data table (all 500 columns)?

Comment: Is your csv file really comma-separated?  I would think that `scan(pipe("cut -f1 -d, Main.csv"))` might be worth a try.

Comment: @BenBolker Takes about 4 seconds. Might as well post the answer ('factor of 10' achieved!).

Comment: @user2763361 I think also `read.table( pipe("cat Main.csv | awk \"{ print $1}\"") )` would work?

Comment: @SimonO101 I'll test it out later. Thank you for your continued contributions.

Comment: @SimonO101 : I think `read.table` will always be slower than `scan`. You can extract the first column using `awk`, `sed` (`sed -e s/,.*$//`), or `cut` -- I don't know which will be fastest but I suspect they'll be close, and `cut` is the most specialized tool for this task ...

Comment: @BenBolker thanks for the info (and thanks for pointing me to `cut` which I didn't know about before). +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest

```
scan(pipe("cut -f1 -d, Main.csv"))
```

This differs from the original proposal (`read.table(pipe("cut -f1 Main.csv"))`) in a couple of different ways:

- since the file is comma-separated and `cut` assumes tab-separation by default, you need to specify `d,` to specify comma-separation
- `scan()` is much faster than `read.table` for simple/unstructured data reads.

According to the comments by the OP this takes about 4 rather than 40+ seconds.

Comment: It is really amazing to see you can nest with Linux command lines before read the file. I can even put my Python cleaner in the pipe command to clean the data before I read the raw file! I am wondering is it possible to read a table from stdin line by line(each row is a line) using scan efficiently?

Comment: Absolutely brilliant.

Comment: @B.Mr.W.: I'm afraid you're not going to be do very much better (I saw your question elsewhere, but your constraints are very strong: it's very hard to think of a way to read line-by-line in R without lots of overhead.)  I don't think `scan` is going to be faster than `readLines`, but why don't you try it and see how it goes?

Comment: @BenBolker Actually you can use `fread` directly with a system command, so this... `fread( "cut -f1 -d, Main.csv" )` *could be* even quicker?

Comment: maybe, but `scan()` really doesn't have very much overhead (in contrast to `read.table()`)

Answer (score 11):

There is a speed comparison of methods to read large CSV files in this [blog](http://statcompute.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/efficiency-of-importing-large-csv-files-in-r/). 
**fread** is the fastest by an order of magnitude.

As mentioned in the comments above, you can use the select parameter to select which columns to read - so:

```
fread("main.csv",sep = ",", select = c("f1") )
```

will work

Comment: can you select which rows to read in? i.e., select rows by columns’ conditions? an `fread` equivalent of `SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM file WHERE col_3 > 30`.